# i18n best practices for javascript react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hell0 folks, I came here to get tips from stacks experts like you.

I'm starting a project in React where multiple language are required. I would like to know what it is the best approach to organise the files. It is good to have one big file with all translations texts or is better to have a single file for each component? Where is the best way to store the user selected language, it is the cookies or localstorage html5 variable?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask] - in this case the question is off topic: _Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise._

Comment: Whats means SO? I'm not asking about operative system, my question is about javascript, sorry if I'm not expressing in a good way. I already searched my question in stackoverflow and due I didn't found the answer I created this post. Please I'm going to need accurate information about why my question is not good in this case. Thanks

Comment: SO = Stack Overflow

Comment: Please read the help - for example https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to see that your question is off topic in several ways. 1: Mostly opinion based 2. Recommendation requested etc.

Comment: I'm surprised that someone that is working on IT since 1986 doesn't know the answer to a simple problem like i18n. My only question was if if better to use a big file or multiple files, but your heart of nerd doesn't allow you to try to make things easy, but I understand, not a big deal. thanks for recommend me google, I never used it and from now I'm going to start using it, looks very good, much better than Altavista. My suggestion, look for a good dentist.

Comment: @osmodiars https://www.i18next.com/principles/namespaces.html might help a little to clarify one file vs multiple files (namespace simplified is a i18next term for "file")